# increase downloading speed?

Tags: c#

I want to donwload a sequence of images from camera using this code.
but the downloading is slow, i can see from image sequence is not smooth if i view it in slideshow.
is there any way i can increase the downloading process speed?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    string ImagePath = Server.MapPath("\\CCTV_Files\\LogFile\\" + String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd_hhmmss}", DateTime.Now) + ".jpg");
    string ip = "http://IP.address.com:80/snapshot.cgi";

    string sourceURL = ip;
    WebRequest req = (WebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sourceURL);
    req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usr", "pwd");
    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();

    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
    bmp.Save(ImagePath);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way i can increase the downloading process speed?

For one thing, you can stop loading the data as a `Bitmap` when you download it. Just save the raw bytes from the body to disk.

Note that you should also use a `using` statement for your response, in order to close it properly.

Also note that if you used `WebClient`, that would quite possibly make the code simpler too - just use [`WebClient.DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx) and let the framework do the work.

Comment: in additional, you can also keep the file in memory instead save it to disk. (save it to disk later)